# Securing my API: concept of access tokens

Tags: tls, webserver, xss, javascript, node.js

First of all I want to excuse for the bad spelling and grammar. English is not my mother tongue.

I have built a JSON communication between a front-end (website) and my Node.js web server. I want to keep in mind, that I might extend my front-end to mobile apps so I allow Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *. Now securing API to my Node.js web server is a big issue. I am new to the topic of security and want to show you a draft of how I want to build up my security before I ask my questions:

General procedure: I am validating every input data on the client side - this includes not only checking if e.g. the supplied email is of a correct format, but also escapes possible XSS inputs with `htmlspecialchars()`. I do an HTTP POST Ajax with my validated data and access token (in HTTP header) to the back-end. In the back-end I discard requests which don't match any DB record with userid (in session object) + access token in my tokenDB. Finally. I am validating data AGAIN on the back-end as well.

How I do my registration and login:

1. Registration form with text fields which are hidden with CSS and email verification.

- hidden fields to prevent spambots
- email verification to make life harder for manual spammers

2. Logging in: email and password is directly sent to the server and if a user record is found in the userDB

- the login succeeds
- userid + randomly generated access token + date > is entered into the tokenDB
- userid is saved in a session and an access token is returned in HTTP header 'accessToken'

I hope this quick draft provides you with enough information for a qualified feedback.

My questions:

1. Is the validation I am doing enough? What possibilities of XSS/other threats haven't I eliminated?
2. Is the `htmlspecialchars()` translation enough to prevent XSS?
3. Did I understand the concept of the access token correctly?
4. How do I create an access token?
5. Is it enough to store the userid in the session?
6. Is HTTPS necessary? -> I don't want to pay for certificates
7. What is your overall impression of my security draft?

I hope you understood my explanation of the concept of securing my API.
I really hope to get some professional feedback!

Comment: Are passwords hashed or in the clear?  HTTPS is absolutely necessary from a security standpoint.  You can generate your own self-signed certificate rather than paying for one.  However this will require users to accept a 3rd-party certificate.  Depending on what your does you could provide login through Facebook/Google+ and have them generate tokens for you.  This link might help with generating your own: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17141292/oauth-2-0-generating-token-and-secret-token  Sorry I can't comment on the other questions.

Comment: im doing the password hashing in backend and saving this hash in the db. So basicly i compare the hash(login-pwd) with db-pwd during authentication/authorization. Thank you for your feedback and the provided link :)